# Getting 408 API request has timed out while accessing Watson discovery

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

[image]

For the past few days i have been trying to access my discovery profile but it is showing -- *408 API request has timed out*, I don't understand what it is i tried on different browsers and different systems.

Answer (score 0):

A 408 HTTP response code is admittedly confusing in this case as 400-level errors typically indicate the client (browser) took too long to send the necessary information so the server timed out the connection when a preconfigured duration has been exceeded.

In this particular case, however, a 502 Gateway Timeout HTTP response would be more appropriate. There are multiple complex interactions happening with some of the pages in Watson Discovery Tooling and sometimes the service experiences slowness. In general, I would investigate the status page for the affected IBM Cloud services to determine whether or not there are any customer impacting events.

To check the status of Watson Discovery and any IBM provided service, I would check https://console.bluemix.net/status to see if any of the slowness or errors line up with your experiences.